# Kotlin firebase realtime database removeValue()

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

In my project, the words are pulled from the database and listed. Users register with google. I keep their favorite words in the database. But I want user to remove fav. I can't give the correct reference. I take the id of the word he clicked below and check if it is in Favorite words. If it is a favorite word, it should be deleted.

```
private fun deleteFav(kelime_id: String) {
    val userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.uid
    val refUser = database.child("/users/${userId}/")
    val key = refUser.push().key


    val refFavori = refUser.child("/favorites/")

    refFavori.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (childSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {

                    val favKelimeId = childSnapshot.child("kelime_id").value

                    Log.i("MEsagge", "inside for")

                    if (kelime_id == favKelimeId) {
                        Log.i("Mesagge", "inside if")
                        Log.i("Mesagge", "${childSnapshot.value}")

                    refFavori.child("$favKelimeId").removeValue()

                    }
                    //Log.i("Database", "child key = $childSnapshot.key")
                    //Log.i("Database", "fav key = $favKelimeId.key")
                }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            // Getting Post failed, log a message
            Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException())
            // ...
        }

    })
}
```

[image]##

Comment: What isn't working about the code you shared? It looks pretty good at first glance. So if you step through it in a debugger line by line, which line is the first one that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the `kelime_id` value of the node(s) to delete, you can use a query to look up what node(s) match that `kelime_id` value:

```
val refFavori = refUser.child("/favorites/")
var query = refFavori.orderByChild("kelime_id").equalTo(favKelimeId)

refFavori.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for (childSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
            childSnapshot.getRef().removeValue()
        }
    }
    ...
```

You'll note that this is a lot simpler, and as an added bonus this doesn't read all `favorites` from the database so it'll be cheaper for you and your users too.

---

If your `kelime_id` values are unique inside the `favorites` node, consider using them as the key instead of generating a unique ID with `push()`. By using the `kelime_id` as the key, you can then delete the necessary node with just:

```
refUser.child("favorites").child(favKelimeId).removeValue()
```